# Создание стартовой страницы на python

Tags: python, веб-программирование, сеть

В чём причина ошибки? Пишу на python. Пытаюсь написать стартовую веб-страницу, отобразить её и правильно заполненную через браузер клиента в ЛВС.
Я попробовал просто написать скрипт такого содержания, который должен выдать ключ='hello word' в шаблон:
скрипт primer.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
#-*-coding: utf-8 
import os
import flask 
import unittest 
import tempfile
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/index.html', methods=['GET'])
def fun1:
    p='Hello word!'
    p.decode('string_escape')
    return render_template('index.html',keyone=str(p))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Простой шаблон (index.html):

```
<!doctype html>
<title> Стартовая страница </title>
{%  if keyone %}
<th>{{keyone}}</th>
{%  else %}
<th>Результат запроса не передан шаблону в виде ключа keyone</th>
{%  endif %}
</tr>
```

Запускаю скрипт:

```
[root@ser py]# python primer.py
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/
 * Restarting with reloader...
```

Обращаюсь с локальной сети:

```
[root@ser py]# wget 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/index.html'
--2012-04-05 10:58:15--  http://127.0.0.1:5000/index.html
Устанавливается соединение с 127.0.0.1:5000... соединение установлено.
Запрос HTTP послан, ожидается ответ... 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
2012-04-05 10:58:17 ОШИБКА 500: INTERNAL SERVER ERROR.
[root@ser py]#
```

В это время с серверной части получаю следующий debag:

```
[root@ser py]# python primer.py
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/
 * Restarting with reloader...
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Apr/2012 10:58:17] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.0" 500 -
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 43539)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 283, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 309, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 322, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 618, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 661, in finish
    self.wfile.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(buffer(data, write_offset, buffer_size))
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

---

Пытаюсь обратиться с компьютера из ЛВС- так в браузере пищет- нет мол соединени (хотя между собой ПЭВМ пингуются), а на серверной части никаких строк не появляется.

Вообщем-то даже если я до максимального упростил всё- картина не поменялась((

Comment: детали проблемы я уже пробовал здесь всё описать:
http://python.su/forum/topic/14219/

Comment: Вы уверены, что так и должно быть? Как бы localhost это 127.0.0.1

    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
    ...
    * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/

Comment: это я так прочитал в мануале по flask, чтобы можно было обращаться к скрипту и с локали и внешне(с ПЭВМ ЛВС клиентской-допустим с браузера

Comment: ПЭВМ ЛВС. Уххх, аж пробрало! :)

Comment: [root@ser py]# wget 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/'
к приметивному скрипту было именно так обращено с локале!
Прошу прощения, если написал по поводу приметивного скрпта немного не так.

Comment: Проверил в локальной сети организованной WiFi-роутером. Ваш пример работоспособен. Копайте в сторону файрволов, настроек сети и т.п.  
Проблема не в скрипте, python или flask.

Comment: отключён-selinux, iptable-разрешены все tcp-пакеты.

Answer (score 2):

Ваш пример кстати полностью рабочий. Возможно неправильно как-то установлен Flask.
В консоли наберите

```
sudo su
apt-get install python-pip
pip install Flask --upgrade
```

Либо проблема в:
- кодировка index.html
- другой процесс слушает порт 5000 (перезагрузите компьютер)
Но в обоих этих случаях совершенно другая ошибка должна быть в traceback
P.S. Ваш пример рабочий за исключением

```
def fun1:
```

Правильно будет `def fun1():`

Comment: )))Понимаю-слегка по универски выразился))

Впринципе мне понятно о чём идёт речь.
Единсвенное поясните где именно прописывается кодировка index.html(шаблона), так как в системе вообще используется utf-8, а скрипт,чтобы отображал правильные символы,которые получает от виндовых машин(БД там крутятся) в кодировке  utf-8, но я пробовал ему указывать cp1251-результат такой же.

Если порт 5000 каким-то процессом занят, то каким образом можно переопределить порт?допустим, чтобы он работал на 5005, а не на 5000 как он запускается по умолчанию?

Comment: Если на windows, то я не знаю, как правильно переустанавливать :) Я Вам дал вариант для Linux.  
Что пишет, если обратиться к несуществующему шаблону? Например у меня формируется traceback прямо в браузер html страницей.  
Что выдает примитивный пример?

    from flask import Flask
    app = Flask(__name__)
    @app.route('/')
    def hello():
        return 'Hello World'
    app.run()

Comment: Я тоже пишу на Linux'e))Семейство RedHat.
Предлагаемы пример Ваш работает-получаю страницу-hello word!в содержании, но только в локале.
Внешне обратиться не получается(((соединения клиенсткой части приложения с серверной-не происходит((

что ещё...
сделал сл.
yum install python-pip.noarch
pip install Flask --upgrade


pip --version
pip 0.6.3

python -V
Python 2.6.6

Comment: А если из локальной сети обратиться к примитивному примеру, то что происходит?  
Вы писали:  

    Обращаюсь с локальной сети:
    [root@ser py]# wget 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/index.html'
Но ведь это обращение к localhost

Comment: если из локальной сети,то ничего ен происходит, за исключением того,что браузер с машины локальной стеи,откуда пытаешься запросить, просто выдаёт информацию, что не удалось подключиться.
Машины естесвенно друг друга "видят", ping'и проходят, единсвенное то,что Линуксовая машины(на которой собсвенно сам скрипт запускается) не в домене общей сети(в основном сеть построена на Windows системах,соответсвенно там и существует Activ Directory)...

Comment: но с ним организрван FTP-соединение, можно подмантировать любую шару к линуксовой машине,используя соотв учётную запись. Но данный факт не явл думаю существенным, так как длопустим php-ые скрипты,работающие через тот же httpd cпокойно работают через web в общей локальной сети

Comment: "Но ведь это обращение к localhost"

так и понятно...ведь это с локали и запрос идёт.
А с локальной сети с клиентсвкой к примеру машины-нет соедиения, там соответсвенно в браузере указываю в поле url:
http://ip_adrr_linuxPVM:5000/index.html

, где ip_adrr_linuxPVM-сетевой адрес линуксовой машины,где крутиться сам скрипт.